# jQuery continuous animation with 'transform: rotateY' always in the same direction

Tags: jquery, css

I want to continously flip an element around its Y-axis, displaying four changing texts on the front and back side and **always have it turn in the same direction**. Each function calls the next one, the last one jumps back to the first. The texts are changed while they are on the backside, i.e. invisible. (BTW: I added perspective and gradients only to make the rotation direction more obvious)

I came up with this (press button to start it):

```js
function turn1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).delay(2000).text('Back1').promise().then(turn2);
};
function turn2() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).text('Front2'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn3); 
};
function turn3() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).delay(2000).text('Back2').promise().then(turn4); 
};
function turn4() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).text('Front1'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(900deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn1); 
};


$('#go').on('click', turn1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 180px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 36px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
#front, #back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#front { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #afc, #4be); 
}
#back { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fa0, #0fa); ; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
} 
button {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="front">Front1</div>
  <div id="back">Back1</div>
</div>
<div class="x"><button id="go">Press to Start</button></div>
```

As you can see, after the fourth turn (when the first function is called again) the element quickly spins back 540 degrees. I can't find a way to reset the Y-rotation to the initial position of 0 and 180 degrees without it spinning back in the other direction. I tried to add a "reset function" at the end of the function chain which is supposed to set the transform parameters to their initial values (without animation), but that doesn't change anything concerning the previous behaviour.

What am I doing wrong here? Is that possible at all?

```js
function turn1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).delay(2000).text('Back1').promise().then(turn2);
};
function turn2() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).text('Front2'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn3); 
};
function turn3() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).delay(2000).text('Back2').promise().then(turn4); 
};
function turn4() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).text('Front1'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(900deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(reset1); 
};
function reset1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'none'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'}).promise().then(turn1);
};


$('#go').on('click', turn1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 180px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 36px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
#front, #back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#front { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #afc, #4be); 
}
#back { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fa0, #0fa); ; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
} 
button {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="front">Front1</div>
  <div id="back">Back1</div>
</div>
<div class="x"><button id="go">Press to Start</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the transition, so one idea is to remove the transition before resetting the position to the initial one.

Here is a basic example:

```js
function turn1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',transition:'2s'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)',transition:'2s'}).delay(2000).text('Back1').promise().then(turn2);
};
function turn2() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).text('Front2'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn3); 
};
function turn3() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(540deg)'}); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).delay(2000).text('Back2').promise().then(turn4); 
};
function turn4() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(720deg)'}).text('Front1'); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(900deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(reset1); 
};
function reset1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'none',transition:'0s'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',transition:'0s'}).delay(200).promise().then(turn1);
};


$('#go').on('click', turn1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 180px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 36px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
#front, #back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#front { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #afc, #4be); 
}
#back { 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fa0, #0fa); ; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
} 
button {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="front">Front1</div>
  <div id="back">Back1</div>
</div>
<div class="x"><button id="go">Press to Start</button></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it - thank you very much, Temani! I already realized that the problem was due to the transition, but hadn't yet found the exact way / the right spot to "reset" that...  There ist still a slight flickering here in the snippet during the reset phase, but that might have to do with the snippet - it doesn't happen when I put the code into the codepen. I'll still have to apply it to the real situation, but I suppose that will work.

Comment: @Johannes yes it seems to happen only on firefox .. I will try to re-work the code later to optimize it, I am pretty sure we can get rid of a lot of jQuery code to make it easier.

Comment: Actually I had tried to hide, then reset, then show the "backside" element while its invisible  (i.e. "turned to the back"), but so far I haven't found a way that  works well.

Comment: @Johannes true, I was also thinking why they was there ... turned all the doc around and found nothing :p

Comment: Splitting the reset function into two functions which first set transition to 0 and then reset the rotate angle seems to improve the situation: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPmpoE